# Python Selenium By raises AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'XPATH'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, attributeerror

I have a problem with Selenium.

```
def main_test():
    chrome_options = Options()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": f"{os.getcwd()}/Music"}
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    dr = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    dr.get(URL)
    print(f"{selenium.__version__=}")
    dr.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a").click()
    dr.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_test()
```

This is my code. I think i followed properly the documentation. Although, when running the app i get this error:

```
selenium.__version__='4.6.0'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrea/Dev/Python/custom_scripts/ytchannel/main.py", line 142, in <module>
    main_test()
  File "/Users/andrea/Dev/Python/custom_scripts/ytchannel/main.py", line 137, in main_test
    dr.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a").click()
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'XPATH'
```

I have no clue on what i'm doing wrong...
I can add every detail possible if needed.

Here my imports:

```
import socket
import httpcore
import re
import os
import json
import selenium
import httpx as web
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
```

Comment: Could you please share the line of code that you use to import the class By?

Comment: Edited the post with my imports

Comment: Is it possible that you use name "By" for any variable or function in your code? I know this is a strange assumption. But I had to ask.

Comment: Nope, but deleting all and recreating all from zero (installing packages and everything) seems to have fixed the problem... (my files are the same, they copy paste)